# Ubuntu Mate 19.10 - check compatibility before install

Tags: mate, nvidia-optimus, samsung

I'm wondering if there is any option to check my laptop compatibility with Ubuntu Mate 19.10.
It's Samsung QX510 laptop loaded with GeForce 420M gpu and Optimus technology. Since about Ubuntu 15.04 I have huge problems with os installation due to Optimus and later it's using only integrated Intel GPU.
Last Ubuntu Mate comes with preinstalled drivers and few improvements for Optimus.
Is there any option to check before install if this OS will solve my problems? Can LiveUSB operate this GPU and allows to do some fps test? Or is there any list of supported cards in Optimus system, I haven't found before?
I will also be grateful for actual Mate users opinions!

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any option to check before install if this OS will solve my problems?

You do not even explain what those issues are so how can we answer that? Please create a question with a problem so someone can try to explain a fix for it if there is an intention to find a fix.

You can install drivers and software during the live USB session and have a look how that operates. But the live USB sessions are slow so the answer is probably no. Not with results you'd expect from a normal installation.

> Can LiveUSB operate this GPU and allows to do some fps test?

Yes, but Ubuntu is not a gaming platform so if that is your target forget about it. We use OpenGL and most games do not. You can install any software during the live session and run it. During a live session install one of the drivers and then do ...

```
$ sudo apt install mesa-utils
$ glxgears
```

Or use the [Phoronix test set](https://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/?k=downloads):

```
$ sudo apt install gdebi-core
$ sudo gdebi phoronix-test-suite_*.deb
$ phoronix-test-suite run unigine-heaven
```

It will require an internet connection during the live session. And again ... the USB live session is slow so will also show low numbers.

It is better to do this with a normal installation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and confirming that I can install and operate drivers during live session. I have used Ubuntu on this laptop for over 8 years and since U 15.04 I have multiple issiues after installation from nouveau problems on boot, no options in nvidia settings to boot loop after installing newest drivers and so on. So I'll try live session, I'm afraid that only full install will show if optimus is working or not, as you said. The main idea is that I already have GeForce in my laptop and I want it to be usable. Linux is becoming more and more gamers friendly, for e.g. thanks to steam.